# Start IPython using non-default version

Tags: python, ipython, virtualenv

I have some strange behavior--ipython is using the wrong interpreter in a virutal environment:

Python 3.4 is my default python interpreter on an Ubuntu system.  I also have python 2.7 installed.

I create a virtual environment to use python 2.7 and install ipython:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 env
source env/bin/activate
pip install ipython
```

IPython module is stored in env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
which ipython reports env/bin/ipython (not /usr/local/bin/ipython)

yet when I type ipython, the interpreter is using python3.4

There is also ipython2 in env/bin which starts ipython using python2.7

What's crazy is a diff on ipython an ipython2 (both in env/bin/) returns nothing!

I am just left scratching my head.

Edit:  OK, so it seems like I had to restart my terminal and now it is working.  Still I think it's weird that which reports one thing, but actually executing the command does another.  Does the terminal do some sort of caching of commands or something?

Comment: Running ipython in a virtualenv will likely make you unhappy/crazy. And when you try to install the universe of things you will want (numpy, scipy, etc.) with their own dependencies (a fortran compiler, blas, lapack, fontconfig, whatever), you may well wish you'd just installed anaconda and been done with it.

Comment: I mean that I've tried to set up ipython with all the usual math/science dependencies and doing it in a virtualenv is always way harder, unlike other python packaging I have ever tried.

Comment: Yes, the shell [does cache commands](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables). N.B. the shell is the program that accepts and runs commands, the terminal is what displays the input and output (and isn't involved here).